# How to represent 4 states as input for an artifical neural network?

Tags: arrays, neural-network

The title might have been a bit unclear. Sadly enough, I could not come up with a better one.

So the problem is the following. There is an array of a fixed size where each position can have 4 states: empty, blocked, positive (a limited value between 0 and 1) and negative (a limited value between 0 and 1 (though this could be 0 to -1)). By limited, I mean that the value can only take the form of 0.1, 0.2, ... 1.0 and each value also only occurs once. Depending on how the array is filled, I would like to predict what the next version of the array will look like. I tried to represent each position in the array as one input node, but I could not figure out how to do this (How to represent all the four states as one number). What also should be noted is that the maximum amount of each state is known. So rather than having each node represent an index in the array, I could have each node represent a state (blocked, -1.0, -0.9, ..., 0.9, 1.0) and then say at what index that state occurs as an input value for that node.

Which way is more practical or efficient for a neural network?

By the way, it is a neural network with one input layer, one hidden layer and one output layer.

Comment: To give you any advice we need to know more about the meaning of the states. Just to be concrete is 0.1 more similar to 0.2 then to 0.7? what is blocked and empty? How does the array evolve?
Moreover if you are trying to predict the next state of the array there are more efficient ways to go about it then a perceptron. 
Explain your problem and not only the raw data representation and someone will be able to help.

Comment: 0.1 and 0.2 are more related to each other than to 0.7.  They are a score. Blocked means nothing can be placed in that array position. I don't really know how the array evolves. That is unknown to me. That is why I wanted to use a neural network. (If you find this, all sounds a bit weird. It is an exercise to find a pattern. I wanted to try and solve this with a neural networks.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you start by using 3 neurons for each cell in your array:

- One which tells the network if the cell is empty. You can just use the values 0 for empty and 1 for non-empty (just an example, other values should work as well, just make sure to be consistent).
- One which does the exact same thing, but it tells the network if the cell is blocked. (again 0 and 1 as possible inputs)
- And finally the Neuron to receive the positive/negative value. You can try various things here. You should probably first try, if it works to just set the value if there is one, and if there is no value you set the input to 0. This might confuse the network a little tough, since it can't see the difference between 0 = null and 0 = 0. If it doesn't work you could try to map all your input values between 0 and 1 (in your case just add 1 and then divide by 2 before passing the value to the network) and input -1 if the cell is blocked/empty.

If you can't get this to work first play around with the parameters for a while, change the amount of hidden layers and neurons, vary the learning-rates and the momentum for training.

If the inputs turn out not to be very good for your task, i would suggest you do what you mentioned before: one neuron for every possible state of each cell. This method will take longer to train, but it should definitely work (if not, your task is rather too comolex for the network, or you need more training time).

Comment: I wasn't aware that attributes could be split up over multiple notes I will try this.

Comment: Depending on the evolution you have, you might need to consider the history and not just 1 state to predict the next one. To make an example, if the system is a moving body and your state is the position, you need at least 2 consecutive states to estimate the next position. In this case you can either just replicate the current state input setup as many times as you like to account for previous states or you can use a more complex setup like a recurrent network.